# Serverless vs Custom server Next.js

Tags: next.js, cdn

I currently try find out and make comparison of advantages and disadvantages of two approaches of building and running application on next.js:

- Custom Server (currently used approach in my project)
- Serverless (approach highly recommended by Next.Js team)

Serverless approach is described as highly recommended approach in Next.js documentation. They also advise to use Vercel, that has build in support for serverless approach in next.js.

My app is using azure cloud for hosting. My app is build and run as custom server approach. I will also use CDN to cache the pages.
Does anyone have experience in implementing next.js in azure infrastructure and CDN with use of:

- Custom server approach?
- Serverless approach?

Are there any pitfalls i should be aware? Which approach is better with azure and CDN? I saw discussion that Custom server approach may cause problems with caching content on CDN.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you do with the custom server? I am not skilled enough to describe the technical consequences, in terms of hosting, perfs etc., but in terms of code, a custom server is adding complexity to your app: you must have a good reason to introduce it, and the default choice should always be using the server Next.js already gives to you.